# count element using Xquery and return the value

Tags: xml, xquery

my xml data:

```
<a>
   <book>
        <pub>John</pub>
   </book>
   <book>
        <pub>John</pub>
    </book>
    <book>
         <pub>Mary</pub>
    </book>
</a>
```

So i want to count number for each  and display them

Expected output:

```
 <result>
         <pub>John</pub>
         <total>2</total>
 </result>
 <result>
         <pub>Mary</pub>
         <total>1</total>
  </result>
```

But my output:

```
 <result>
         <pub>John</pub>
         <total>1</total>
 </result>
<result>
         <pub>John</pub>
         <total>1</total>
 </result>
 <result>
         <pub>Mary</pub>
         <total>1</total>
  </result>
```

code i using :

```
for $b in /a/book
let $count := count($b/pub)
for $pub in $b/pub
return
     <result> {$pub} <total>{$count}</total></result>
```

it keep looping the same data but not group it . even i use distinct-values it's still same. what error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping works using `distinct-values`. You can count all the `book`s or `pub`s and filter only the ones that match the current iteration.

This:

```
let $b := /a/book/pub
  for $pub in distinct-values($b)
      let $count := count($b[. eq $pub])
      return <result>
                <pub>{$pub}</pub> 
                <total>{$count}</total>
             </result>
```

will produce:

```
<result>
   <pub>John</pub>
   <total>2</total>
</result>
<result>
   <pub>Mary</pub>
   <total>1</total>
</result>
```

Comment: want to understand. what is this code for let $count := count($b[. eq $pub]) why got . inside?

Comment: `$pub` is the *current* node (`/a/book/pub`) *in the context of the `for` loop*. `$b` is a set containing *all* nodes (total of 3): `/a/book/pub[1]`, `/a/book/pub[2]` and `/a/book/pub[3]`. Basically in each iteration of the loop, you compare the current node `$pub` with all three nodes, and select only the ones which have the same string value as `$pub`. The `.` inside  the predicate "[...]" represents the node itself (predicates in XPath are contextual). Since I'm relying on the string value. You could also replace the `.` for `node()` or `text()`.

Comment: If you remove the predicate `[. eq $pub]` you should get the total value always (`3`), since `$b` doesn't change in the loop. If you use `count($pub)` you will always get `1`, because there is only one `pub` per iteration of the loop.

Comment: so i can change to count($b[text() = $pub/text()])?

Answer (score 2):

If using an XQuery 3.0 capable XQuery processor, you can also take advantage of the `group by` flwor statement:

```
for $book in /a/book
let $publisher := $book/pub
group by $publisher
return
  <result>
    <pub>{ $publisher }</pub>
    <count>{ count($book) }</count>
   </result>
```